# What does vertical-align need to work?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a very simple test html site like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="height:500px">
    <img style="height:200px; vertical-align:middle;" src="http://i.imgur.com/BidLR.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the image is not displayed vertically centered in the div. (At least in Google Chrome). What does it need that the image is rendered centered?

Comment: Since an image is an _inline_ element, `vertical-align` on it specifies its position with respect to the _surrounding text_. CSS is notoriously bad at vertical-centering of block elements.

Comment: Maybe try using vertical-align:50% or vertical-align:-50%, depending on whether the image starts off near the top or bottom of the div? Sorry if this is wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vertical-align` will vertically center the image on it's line. You need to set a `line-height` that's taller than the image.

See the style area:
http://jsfiddle.net/5ugDx/

Comment: Thanks. That's it. Also I did forget the <!DOCTYPE html> which strangely causes chrome to not center the element. Is that normal?

Comment: without a doctype, most browsers revert to what's called "quirksmode". It's never good to leave out your doctype declaration :P

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 6 different ways to center your image. Choose one:

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/